# What's the error in my script?

Tags: javascript, onclick, refresh

I'm having three buttons A,B,C. When i click the button A the C button should hide (it's not a problem), when i click the button B the page should be refreshed ( history.go(0) ),
the C button should be showed and the B button should hide, i tried by using the following code the process happened (i.e) C button showed but the B button didn't hide (it's hide only for a fraction of seconds and suddenly it's showed).......

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#A").click(function() {
        $("#C").hide()
    });

    $("#B").click(function() {
        history.go(0)
        $("#C").show();
        $("#B").hide();         
    });
});

</script>
```

May be, due to the page refresh it will show the button B, but i'm not sure. suggest me some idea to overcome this issue.
                   Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, It is because you refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set default values at start of the document

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#C").show();
    $("#B").hide();         

    $("#A").click(function() {
        $("#C").hide()
    });

    $("#B").click(function() {
        history.go(0)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#C").show();

    $("#B").hide();

    $("#A").click(function() {
        $("#C").hide();
        $("#B").show();
    });

    $("#B").click(function() {
        history.go(0)

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`history.go(0)` is a page refresh and how can you expect a click action to happen on a page refresh where the page is in a new state.

Probably call the  `$("#C").show(); $("#B").hide();` on page load and on  `$("#B").click` just refresh the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#C").show();

 $("#B").hide();


    $("#A").click(function() {
        $("#C").hide()
    });

    $("#B").click(function() {
        history.go(0)

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are refreshing the page and then doing the hide. When you refresh a page, you cancel all the js execution, and therefore the code after history.go(0) does not execute at all.

Answer (score 0):

When browser interpretes history.go(), your page is refreshed and the rest of your script isn't executed.